# Ruby Thread with "watchdog"

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sockets, io

I'm implementing a ruby server for handling sockets being created from GPRS modules. The thing is that when the module powers down, there's no indication that the socket closed.

I'm doing threads to handle multiple sockets with the same server. What I'm asking is this: Is there a way to use a timer inside a thread, reset it after every socket input, and that if it hits the timeout, closes the thread? Where can I find more information about this?

EDIT: Code example that doesn't detect the socket closing

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.open(41000)
loop do
    Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
        puts "Client connected"

        begin
            loop do
                line = client.readline

                open('log.txt', 'a') { |f|
                    f.puts line.strip
                }
            end
        rescue
            puts "Client disconnected"
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Use [eventmachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine)! Because it is ♥.

Comment: how would event machine help in this case?

Comment: You can't really tell the socket closed. It can take hours, days and maybe months until your application notices the socket closed. You need to ping-bong between the client(GPRS module) and your server.

Comment: Why event machine would be a good choice is because it lets you separate all this network logic from the application logic. Now, you would probably still need to implement the the ping-pong mechanism with event machine (however, I think EM has a heart beat mechanism, but I didn't find it reliable), but it will allow for much greater concurrency and it will save you a lot of headache while trying to make an asynchronous server!

Comment: And EventMachine is a reactor pattern architecture so it is essentially like node.js, but better (better only because I am a Ruby supremacist).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a heartbeat mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, your sockets are inexplably closing because you're not catching exceptions that are raised when they are closed by the remote end.

you need to wrap the connection handler in an exception catching block.

Without knowing what module/model you're using I will just fudge it and say you have a `process_connection` routine.  So you need to do something like this:

```
def process_connection(conn)
    begin
        # do stuff
    rescue Exception => e
        STDERR.print "Caught exception #{e}: #{e.message}\n#{e.backtrace}\n"
    ensure
        conn.close
    end
end
```

This will catch all exceptions and dump them to stderr with a stack trace.  From there you can see what is causing them, and possibly handle them more gracefully elsewhere.

Comment: I tried it before coming here... but to no avail... the socket doesnt appear to close...

Answer (score 0):

Just check the standar API Timeout:

```
require 'timeout'
status = Timeout::timeout(3){sleep(1)}
puts status.inspect
status = Timeout::timeout(1){sleep(2)}
```